# Firefox Saved Logins Once cleared never asks again?

Tags: firefox, security, privacy, url

If I delete a login/password in firefox by deleting it from the url list under **Options** > **Privacy and Security** > **Saved Logins** , that url will never offer again the option to save a login/password.

I have poked around quite a bit on this and not figured out a way to reset just one url site.

A master password is in use.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The setting to request the master password every time a password is used was removed from Firefox. You need an extension like [Master Password Timeout](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/master-password-timeout-upd/) to make Firefox forget your master password again.